# Killing a soldier: nanomachine warning

Tags: metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

So, I was playing in a stealth-ish way through chapter 2, when I realized something: when I killed a PMC soldier, some seconds passed by, when a running comrade comes blazing through from the middle of the forest to see if something is wrong!!

Then, he checks his colleague body and enters a caution state.
I've never read about this anywhere. So, apparently, this is the main downside of killing someone if you want to be stealthy.

My questions are: am i getting something wrong? 
Does this happen through the entire game or only in this particular chapter?
What's the explanation for the warning? Nanomachines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens (mostly) through the entire game. In some scenes, like the very begining of that chapter, if you sniper-kill the PMC to prevent them from killing the rebels, is very likely to trigger a caution stage, but they'll not be looking for Snake. I really can't explain it to myself, how do they know Snake killed the PMC and not the militia?, I don't know; even using a sniper might get you the attention of the PMC soldiers.

Snake's nanomachines are supposed to be a string apart from the one in the PMC soldiers (generations apart even), so they may have basic interaction but it's highly unlikely that they know Snake's actions through them. Furthermore, the militia know snake is helping them without them seeing him do so, and they don't have nanomachines, so that theory's out.

However caution mode will not get you an alert status (it'll get you closer to alert), but it will make it harder to stay in stealth, and if you're going for the higher ranks like Fox Hound or Big Boss, you shouldn't be killing anyone either.